# Can not get param by json method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
http://localhost:3000/users.json?q=lala
```

I want to get json by sending some string,

But I can not get the expected string 'lala' in params[:q]

```
p(params) `{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"users", "locale"=>"en"}`
```

controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    # @users = User.all
    @users = User.order(:name)
    (1..100).each {p(params)}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: @users.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")}
    end

  end
```

This is my `route.rb`

```
  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    resources :articles
    resources :users
    root to: 'articles#index'
  end
  match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"), constraints: lambda { |req| !req.path.starts_with? "/#{I18n.default_locale}/" }, :via => [:get]
  match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}"), :via => [:get]
  match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}"), :via => [:get]
```

Comment: for me `params` are coming fine,could you please verify in routes.rb having `resources :users`.

Comment: in routes.rb you gave `scope ":locale"` so routes will generate like `en/users` i think so this might be the problem.please verify it http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: @Kingston thanks for your help, but could you tell me the more detail answer? how to fix it by changing my route. thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you put `resources :users` outside the `scope ":locale"`,then the routes will generate normal routes like

```
GET     /users  users#index     users_path
```

RESTful routing creates by default.

Please see [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Hi I know put it outsite can fix the problem,

Comment: but I still need the `locale` so I can not use your solution, sorry

Comment: then try to change your url like `/en/users.json`.